# Rolling average over predictions

Tags: javascript, performance, react.js

I am using a Deep Learning model I trained and want to improve its accuracy by implementing a rolling average prediction. I have already done it but want to improve it as I am making predictions on every 3 frames.

**Input:**
Each index represents a class and the respective prediction the model makes.
Order is not alphanumeric as its based on my folder structure during training

1st Index : Class 0

2nd Index : Class 10

3rd Index : class 5

```
[
  0.9288286566734314,
  0.008770409040153027,
  0.062401000410318375,
]
```

So the goal is to store the highest probability and its index at every frame. Based on the structure I mentioned above I add the probability to its class. Every time a new probability gets added I increase a counter. Once the counter reaches N, I find the class which has the most predictions, I sum the probabilities and return the average of it and the respective class it belongs to.

```
N = 5
Prediction {
"0": [0.9811,0.9924, 0.8763],
"5": [0.9023],
"10": [0.9232]
}
```

**Code in React(model is loaded on a mobile phone)**

Rolling Prediction does the averaging of the predictions and is passed in the array of predictions mentioned in the input.

There are 2 helper functions to find the sum and to find the max value and max index in an array.

```
  const [allPredictions, setAllPredictions] = useState({
    "0": [],
    "5": [],
    "10": []
  });
  let queueSize = 0;
  let total = 0;

  const rollingPrediction = arr => {
    const { max, maxIndex } = indexOfMax(arr);
    const maxFixed = parseFloat(max.toFixed(2));
    if (maxIndex === 0) {
      allPredictions["0"].push(maxFixed);
      queueSize += 1;
    } else if (maxIndex === 1) {
      allPredictions["10"].push(maxFixed);
      queueSize += 1;
    } else if (maxIndex === 2) {
      allPredictions["5"].push(maxFixed);
      queueSize += 1;
    }
    console.log(`Queue : ${queueSize}`);
    if (queueSize > 4) {
      console.log("Queue Size Max");
      const arr1 = allPredictions["0"].length;
      const arr2 = allPredictions["5"].length;
      const arr3 = allPredictions["10"].length;

      if (arr1 > arr2 && arr1 && arr3) {
        const sum = sumOfArray(allPredictions["0"]);
        const prob = sum / arr1;
        console.log(`Awareness level 0 | Probability: ${prob}`);
      } else if (arr2 > arr1 arr2 && arr3) {
        const sum = sumOfArray(allPredictions["5"]);
        const prob = sum / arr2;
        console.log(`Awareness level 5 | Probability: ${prob}`);
      } else if (arr3 > arr2 arr3 && arr1) {
        const sum = sumOfArray(allPredictions["10"]);
        const prob = sum / arr3;
        console.log(`Awareness level 10 | Probability: ${prob}`);
      } else {
        console.log("No rolling prediction");
      }
      queueSize = 0;
      allPredictions["0"] = [];
      allPredictions["5"] = [];
      allPredictions["10"] = [];
    }
  };

  const sumOfArray = arr => {
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        total += arr[i];
    }
    return total; 
  };

  const indexOfMax = arr => {
    if (arr.length === 0) {
      return -1;
    }
    let max = arr[0];
    let maxIndex = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] > max) {
        max = arr[i];
        maxIndex = i;
      }
    }
    return {
      max,
      maxIndex
    };
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that, in `rollingPrediction`, you just need the `maxIndex`, once that you already can access the `max` in `arr` with it.

Also, since that you need the `maxIndex` to find the class, you can just store the classes in an array with every class stored in the correspondent index.

---

To find which array has the most predictions, you will receive an array and evaluate it to one value. In cases like this, I think that you can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

- In the callback function, check which array has the bigger length
- The initial value will be `[null, []]`,  to check if there's one bigger array and  to have an array to compare in the callback function.

---

In `indexOfMax` you can use [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) with [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) since performance it's not a problem in this case, but you can use reduce too.

---

Suggestion: In `sumOfArray`, you receive an array as parameter and want to evaluate to one value. Maybe you can use reduce once again.

```js
// ...
const classesIndexed = ["0", "10", "5"];
// suggestion: once that you know the classes order, this could be:
// const classesIndexed = Object.keys(allPredictions); 

const rollingPrediction = arr => {
  const maxIndex = indexOfMax(arr);
  if(maxIndex === -1) {
    return;
  }
  const maxFixed = parseFloat(arr[maxIndex].toFixed(2));
  allPredictions[classesIndexed[maxIndex]].push(maxFixed);
  queueSize++;

  if (queueSize <= 4) {
    const [className, bigger] = Object.entries(allPredictions)
      .reduce(
        (acc, act) => acc[1].length >= act[1].length ? acc : act,
        [null, []]
      );
    if (!className) {
      const sum = sumOfArray(bigger);
      const prob = sum / bigger.length;
      console.log(`Awareness level ${className} | Probability: ${prob}`);
    } else {
      console.log("No rolling prediction");
    }
    // ...
};
// ...
const indexOfMax = (arr = []) => arr.indexOf(Math.max(arr))
```